# Rename and uploaded file?

Tags: php

Is there a simple way to rename an upload file? I'd like to append `$_POST['bid']` to the front of the file that was uploaded.

Comment: Your question is bit confusing, you want to rename an already uploaded file or file which is about to be uploaded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Rename a already uploaded file

Use rename function http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php

It is as easy as

```
rename ("/folder/file.ext", "/folder/newfile.ext");
```

---

### Rename a file during upload

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILE['myfile'][tmp_name],$_POST['bid'].$_FILE['myfile'][name]);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
bool move_uploaded_file ( string $filename , string $destination )
```

In `$destination`, you can specify any filename you want.

[move_uploaded_file on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

Answer (score 0):

When uploaded, the file is in the temporary folder and should be moved to the folder you want it in.

While moving the file you can give it any name.

Check out: http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php for more info.